# UniRx troubleshooting Delay/Throttle with my Object spawner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reactive-programming

I'm new to UniRx, so right now I'm just experimenting. I'm trying to make a spawner by making a GameObject create a new object if the previous was destroyed.

Some of it works but when I destroy the object it is not recreated every time.
My thoughts are that as long as I destroy it within the given cooldown time it is recreated, but I would like to be able to kill it whenever but have it spawn with a delay matching the random cooldown time.

I'm trying to keep track of destroyed objects with an array to limit it to a certain amount of objects.

I have tried using Delay instead of Throttle with the same result.

```
private ReactiveProperty<GameObject[]> spawnedObjects;

public void spawnNewObject(int index)
{
    if (spawnedObjects.Value[index] == null)
    {
        GameObject newSpawn = Instantiate(spawnObject, transform.position + offset, Quaternion.identity, transform);
        spawnedObjects.Value[index] = newSpawn;
    }
}

private void setupSpawner()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnedObjects.Value.Length; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        spawnedObjects
            .ObserveEveryValueChanged(spawns => spawns.Value[j])
            .Throttle(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Random.Range(timeFromTo.x, timeFromTo.y)))
            .Subscribe(_ => spawnNewObject(j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems ObserveEveryValueChanged does not observe the value becoming null, so I had to make a workaround, I am now observing activeSelf and instead of destroying I set it to false, then during the spawn I override the element with the new one and destroy the old, this seems to work fine with the observer :)

```
protected ReactiveProperty<GameObject[]> spawnedObjects;

public virtual void spawnNewObject(int index)
{
    if (spawnedObjects.Value[index] != null)
    {
        GameObject old = spawnedObjects.Value[index];
        GameObject newSpawn = Instantiate(spawnObject, transform.position + offset, Quaternion.identity, transform);
        spawnedObjects.Value[index] = newSpawn;
        Destroy(old);
    }
}

public virtual void setupSpawner()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnedObjects.Value.Length; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        spawnedObjects
            .ObserveEveryValueChanged(spawns => spawns.Value[j].activeSelf)
            .Where(active => active == false)
            .Throttle(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Random.Range(timeFromTo.x, timeFromTo.y)))
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                spawnNewObject(j);
            });
    }
}
```